# If $Z$ is a complex number such that $ |Z|\ge 2 $ the the range of values of $\ |Z+\frac{1}2|\ $ is?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If Z is a complex number such that $ |Z|\ge 2 $ the the range of values of $\ |Z+1/2|\ $ is ?

**My try**

I tried using the triangle inequality according to which ||Z| +|1/2||  $\ge$  |Z+ 1/2| this implies  5/2 $\ge$ |Z+1/2|

then |Z-(-1/2)| $\ge$ |Z| -|1/2| then |Z+1/2| $\ge$ 3/2 then |Z+ 1/2 | $\in$ [3/2,5/2]

but the answer given is |Z+ 1/2 | $\in$ (1,2)

If there is some mistake please point out or confirm that the method is right and the answer given may be wrong . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot establish an upper bound on $|Z+1/2|$ because we have no upper bound on $|Z|$. You write $$|Z+1/2|\leq ||Z|+|1/2||=|Z|+1/2.$$ We know that $|Z|\geq 2$, but this doesn't really help us. All we know is that $|Z|+1/2\geq 5/2$, but the inequality is going the wrong way to use in the chain above. So we cannot bound $|Z+1/2|$ above. For instance, $Z$ could equal $10^n$ for any value of $n$.

Comment: look thatis the same thing is there something wrong in the  ||Z| +|1/2|| ≥ |Z+ 1/2| this implies 5/2 ≥ |Z+1/2| step

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original post. I have edited my answer to explain why you cannot bound above.

Comment: so the conclusion is the question is wrong as we cannot upper bound the region

Comment: that's the only thing I can think of.