# Suppose $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are complex numbers such that $\frac{Z_1-2Z_2}{2-Z_1\bar Z_2}$ is unimodular. Where does $Z_1$ lie?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

***Question***

Suppose $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are complex numbers such that $\frac{Z_1-2Z_2}{2-Z_1\bar Z_2}$ is unimodular. Where does $Z_1$ lie?

***My try*** 
given that $\left|\frac{Z_1-2Z_2}{2-Z_1\bar Z_2}\right|= 1$, we have

$$|Z_1-2Z_2|= |2-Z_1\bar Z_2|$$

What to do next ?

Comment: When you say "where $Z$ lies" do you mean "where do $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ lie"?  If not, what is $Z$?

Comment: i forgot to mention it was $\ Z_1 $ i have edited the question

Comment: "What to do next ?" A: Square, expand and collect.

Comment: In general, if $w,z\in\mathbb{C}$ are such that $w\bar{z}\neq 1$ and $\left|\frac{z-w}{1-w\bar{z}}\right|=1$, then $|w|=1$ or $|z|=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left |\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar z_2}\right|=1$$
Square both sides,
$$\implies (z_1-2z_2)(\bar z_1-2\bar z_2)=(2-z_1\bar z_2)(2-\bar z_1z_2)$$
Now, simplify things, you get:
$$|z_1|^2+4|z_2|^2=4+|z_1|^2|z_2|^2$$
$$\implies |z_1|^2=\frac{4(1-|z_2|^2)}{1-|z_2|^2}$$
Now for $|z_2| \neq 1$,
$$\implies |z_1|^2=4$$
$$\implies |z_1|=2$$
Hence, $z_1$ represents a circle having radius $2$ units, centred at origin in the complex plane.

Comment: If $|z_2|\ne1$.

Comment: @Did Yes, I should have mentioned it, thanks!

Comment: okay hey @Nikunj what do u think about this one [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721262/if-z-is-a-complex-number-such-that-z-ge-2-the-the-range-of-values-of) do u think they got this one wrong in the JEE

Comment: Nope, they asked the minimum value of z, the minimum would be $\frac {3}{2}$ the maximum wouldn't be defined as you wouldn't have the upper bound.